# Error when running TFS distributed load test

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, load-testing

Whenever we try and run a distributed load test on our TFS test controller, we get the following error message:

> The ObjectManager found an invalid number of fixups. this usually indicates a problem in the formatter.

[image]

I've created the world's simplest test to ensure it's not a problem with my code:

My test looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

And the load-test configuration looks like this:

[image]

### Environment

The environment is very simple - 1 TFS server, 1 TFS Test Controller, and 1 TFS Test Agent (on separate servers).

### Things I have tried

I have tried recreating the LoadTest2010 database using the [instructions here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182600.aspx).

I have confirmed that the same test works both locally, and on Visual Studio Online load testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you've found a solution to this yourself but I was having the same problem and have been able to resolve it by doing the following:
1) After you have created the loadtest save and close it.
2) open your loadtest in notepad or notepad++
3) scroll to the bottom and locate **LoadGeneratorLocations**
4) delete this tag and the content in between the tag. Save and close.
5) open your loadtest in visual studio.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Amazing! We added the location to run it using Visual Studio Online. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RB Maybe your test agents are not VS2013 update 5 or VS2015 while your client is?

Comment: @Albert D'oh! That is definitely the case. I'll look into upgrading the test agents :)

Comment: Glad I could help. @Albert might have to do the same on my machines.